# Different ingress in different Namespace in kubernetes

Tags: namespaces, kubernetes

I have created two different namespaces for different environment. one is devops-qa and another is devops-dev. I created two ingress in different namespaces. So while creating ingress of qa env in devops-qa namespace, the rules written inside ingress of qa is working fine. Means I am able to access the webpage of qa env. The moment I will create the ingress of dev env in devops-dev namespace, I will be able to access the webpage of dev env but wont be able to access the webpage of qa. And when I delete the dev ingress then again I will be able to access the qa env website

Below is the ingree of both dev and qa env.

**Dev Ingress**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
  name: cafe-ingress-dev
  namespace: devops-dev
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - cafe-dev.example.com
    secretName: default-token-drk6n
  rules:
  - host: cafe-dev.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: miqpdev-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

**QA Ingress**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx" 
  name: cafe-ingress-qa
  namespace: devops-qa
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - cafe-qa.example.com
    secretName: default-token-jdnqf
  rules:
  - host: cafe-qa.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /greentea
        backend:
          serviceName: greentea-svc
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /blackcoffee
        backend:
          serviceName: blackcoffee-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

The token mentioned in the ingress file is of each namespace. And the nginx ingress controller is running in QA namespace
How can i run both the ingress and will be able to get all the websites deployed in both dev and qa env ?

Comment: what Ingress Controller are you using ?

Comment: I am using nginx-plus

Comment: Is each token `default-token-jdnqf` or `default-token-drk6n` a TLS certificate that you created yourself and self signed?

Answer (score 11):

I actually Solved my problem. I did everything correct. But only thing I did not do is to map the hostname with the same ip in Route53. And instead of accessing the website with hostname, I was accessing it from IP. Now after accessing the website from hostname, I was able to access it :)

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you posted [here and got your answer](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/76). The solution is to deploy a different Ingress for each namespace. However, deploying 2 Ingresses complicates matters because one instance has to run on a non-standard port (eg. 8080, 8443).

I think this is better solved using DNS. Create the CNAME records `cafe-qa.example.com` and `cafe-dev.example.com` both pointing to `cafe.example.com`. Update each Ingress manifest accordingly. Using DNS is somewhat the standard way to separate the Dev/QA/Prod environments.

Comment: Hey Eugene, I am still not able to resolve the issue. I tried giving different host, but still I am not able to access the websites of both namespace. The nginx ingress controller is running in QA .

Comment: Does "different host" mean you use `cafe-qa.example.com` and `cafe-dev.example.com`? Can you update the question with your new config?

Comment: one thing more, I am using nginx-plus provided by Nginx not by kubernetes... So will it support this facility.

Comment: I can't figure out why. I have similar Ingress manifests like yours, but mine work flawlessly. I use Traefik though. Are the manifests in your question exactly the same as the one in your deployment? Also, did you deploy the nginx ingress controller using the tutorial @radek-goblin-pieczonka provided?

Comment: Hi Eugene, I guess I am facing issue cause i am using ingress controller provided by Nginx Inc, not of kubernetes Nginx. I am setting it up now. If you have any blog that will help me to smoothly setup the nginx controller for kuberenetes nginx ingress then pls share with me, cause official documentaion (github) hasnot explained it well.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/master/controllers/nginx) suggested by @radek-goblin-pieczonka is excellent. Can you use other Ingress controllers? This [tutorial for Traefik](https://medium.com/@patrickeasters/using-traefik-with-tls-on-kubernetes-cb67fb43a948#.pnp56pvx6) definitely works.

Comment: Hi Eugene I tried to follow the doc, but after running the traefik pod, I tried to see the log of that pod, then I am getting  "  ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: E0801 11:58:08.036915       1 reflector.go:199] github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/reflector.go:94: Failed to list *v1.Secret: Get https://10.254.0.1:443/api/v1/secrets?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.254.0.1:443: i/o timeout "

Comment: Have you ever faced this kind of issue

Comment: Is Traefik serving your sites correctly? The error is due to Traefik not having the permission (ie. the RBAC policy) to access Secrets on kube-apiserver. The error can be ignored if your setup works. I recall that the developers are aware of it.

Comment: can you have more than 1 ingress controller per namespace? I attempted to solve this by creating two and giving the static IP addresses to my respective CNAME records and had the same issue detailed above? does this only work with 1 ingress per namespace?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, found a way to resolve it:

you just need to add the "**--watch-namespace**" argument to the ingress controller that sits under the ingress service that you've linked to your ingress resource. Then it will be bound only to the services within the same namespace as the ingress service and its pods belong to.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
namespace:  my-namespace
name: nginx-ingress-controller
spec: 
  replicas: 1
selector:
  matchLabels:
    name: nginx-ingress-lb
template: 
  metadata: 
    labels: 
      name: nginx-ingress-lb
  spec:
    serviceAccountName: ingress-account
    containers: 
      - args: 
          - /nginx-ingress-controller
          - "--default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-http-backend"
          - "--default-ssl-certificate=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/secret-tls"
          - "--watch-namespace=$(POD_NAMESPACE)"
        env: 
          - name: POD_NAME
            valueFrom: 
              fieldRef: 
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: POD_NAMESPACE
            valueFrom: 
              fieldRef: 
                fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        name: nginx-ingress-controller
        image: "quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.24.1"
        livenessProbe: 
          httpGet: 
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
        ports: 
          - containerPort: 80
            name: http
            protocol: TCP
          - containerPort: 443
            name: https
            protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
namespace:  my-namespace
name: nginx-ingress
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: https
  selector:
    name: nginx-ingress-lb
```

Comment: You can accomplish the isolation by :

- using a different namespaces (you have devops-dev and devops-qa)

- using diffrent ingresses clases per namespace : 
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx-dev"
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx-qa" 

- using - "--watch-namespace=$(POD_NAMESPACE)" in the ingress deployment template.spec.containers.args
This made the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create nginx ingress cotroller in kube-system namespace instead of creating it in QA namespace.